# Run on the master workbook, check if there are any new or deleted worksheets in the daily input workbook

Tags: vba

I am trying to figure out how to do this, any guidance would be great.

**Setup:** I work between 2 workbooks called `Master` and `Daily Input`

- The `Daily Input` file contains 10 worksheets, each worksheet = 1 person's name. + 1 worksheet named "Input Template"
- The `Master` workbook contains a bunch of different worksheets for different calculations. + 9 worksheet with the team member's names.

*Assume currently there are 9 people in the team.*

When new people join or leave the team, they will open / delete worksheets from the `Daily Input` workbook.
Therefore I want to:

New Team Member added a new worksheet scenario:

1. If `Daily Input` have a worksheet that `Master` does not (except Input Template), then create a new worksheet in `Master` with the same name. The new worksheet is copied from `Output Template` that is already in the `Master` file.
2. If `Master` have a worksheet that `Daily Input` does not (except a few worksheets for calculation), then just prompt a messagebox.

Currently I have written something that extracts all the sheet names from the `Daily Input` file, and then put it in the `Master File` but I am not sure how to make use of that...

Maybe load both sheet name lists into an array and compare?

```
Sub ObtainNameList()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WkBk_Input As Workbook
Dim WkBk_Active As Workbook
Dim GetListFName As String
Dim GetListFPath As String
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim i As Integer



    Set WkBk_Active = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    FPath = WkBk_Active.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B1")
    FName = WkBk_Active.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B2")
    Set WkBk_Input = Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath & "\" & FName)


    WkBk_Active.Worksheets("NameList").Range("A:A").ClearContents

    For i = 1 To WkBk_Input.Sheets.Count
    WkBk_Active.Worksheets("NameList").Range("A" & i).Value = WkBk_Input.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

    WkBk_Input.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and explain what you already tried, for more, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would create a separate worksheet in the Master workbook that keeps a running list of the usernames (and possibly other pertinent details). Then you just compare the list of worksheet names from the Daily Input to the existing list in the Master. If you find any differences, then you must decide what to do -- for example: automatically add a new worksheet template for the new user, send an email to the admin (you?) that a new user was detected, etc.

Comment: Do you want to trigger this from the master or the user workbook?

Comment: @PeterT  Ya, if found a new user, then add a new worksheet template in the Master workbook, the template is already a sheet in Master workbook and can be copied.

Comment: @Harassed Dad I am running this from the Master workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to work, but I'm on my phone so can't actually check it:

```
Sub CheckandCreate()
Dim Fpath As String
Dim Fname As String
Dim master As Workbook
Set master = ThisWorkbook 'assume running in master
Dim daily As Workbook
'set daily path and name here
Set daily = Workbooks.Open(Fpath & "\" & Fname)
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In daily.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name
      Case "Input Template"  'add ay other sheet names you want to ignore here
      Case Else
           If SheetNotExist(ws.Name, master) Then
               AddSheet (ws.Name)
           End If
   End Select
Next ws
daily.Close False  'close daily without saving
End Sub

Function SheetNotExist(sheetname As String, where As Workbook) As Boolean
     On Error GoTo nope
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = where.Worksheets(sheetname) 'if sheet exists this will work
     SheetNotExist = False
     Exit Function
nope:
     SheetNotExist = True  'will only get here if sheet doesn't exist
End Function

Sub AddSheet(sheetname As String)

     Dim ws As Worksheet
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output Template").Copy _ after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)   'copy to end of workbook
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 'new worksheet
     ws.Name = sheetname
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. And it was so much simpler than what I was had planned (which involved copying and then arrays and then comparing)